# How to VACUUM RoomDatabase?

Tags: android, performance, android-room

how do I VACUUM my `RoomDatabase` for my Application? 
I build my entire Application around Room and at a certain point one big table gets deleted reguarly and later filled again.

I tried to create an additional DAO-Interface with the Query:

```
@Dao
public interface GenericDao {
    @Query("VACUUM")
    void vacuum();
}
```

but I get the Error:

```
Error:(13, 10) error: UNKNOWN query type is not supported yet. You can use:SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE
```

Is there a workaround?

Basically what I need is, that once my Table gets completely emptied, **Autoincrement** starts at 1 again.

I'm fairly new to Database Design, so please be understanding if this is against best Practice.
And yes: I exhausted Google and every other Platform I know.

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just do a DELETE, it clears the table... You shouldn't need id's to reset

Comment: @cricket_007 actually vacuum reclaims the free space, which delete command can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dao can look as follows :

```
@Dao
public interface RawDao {
    @RawQuery
    int vacuumDb(SupportSQLiteQuery supportSQLiteQuery);
}
```

Run the query like this :

```
rawDao.vacuumDb(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("VACUUM"));
```

Comment: thanks! even though i found an alternative, I will give this a try too as soon as possible :)

Comment: @simon can you share that alternative too?

Comment: @bilal i don't remember clearly honestly since I reworked the entire app since then. But I think I ended up implementing my own index and incrementing it by myself. So not really a real alternative tbh.

Comment: @simon for me, this answer worked. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a workaround?

Call `getOpenHelper()` on your `RoomDatabase` subclass, to get a `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper`. Call `getWritableDatabase()` on it to get a `SupportSQLiteDatabase`. Then, since I don't think that `VACUUM` returns a result set, call `execSQL("VACUUM")` on the `SupportSQLiteDatabase`.

> Basically what I need is, that once my Table gets completely emptied, Autoincrement starts at 1 again.

IMHO, you should not be making any assumptions about how autoincrement fields get incremented.